# C Compile Error: array type has incomplete element type

Tags: c, arrays, struct, compiler-errors

```
#include <stdio.h>    
typedef  struct
    {       
        int   num ;
    } NUMBER ;

    int main(void)
    {   
        struct NUMBER array[99999];
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm getting a compile error:

```
error: array type has incomplete element type
```

I believe the problem is that I'm declaring the array of struct incorrectly. It seems like that's how you declare it when I looked it up.

Answer (score 14):

```
struct NUMBER array[99999];
```

should be

```
NUMBER array[99999];
```

because you already `typedef`ed your struct.

---

EDIT: As OP is claiming that what I suggested him is not working, I compiled this test code and it is working fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef  struct
{
    int   num ;
} NUMBER ;

int main(void)
{
    NUMBER array[99999];
    array[0].num = 10;
    printf("%d", array[0].num);
    return 0;
}
```

See the [running code](http://ideone.com/Kj91B0).

Comment: or `struct NUMBER{int num;};` without the typedef

Comment: NUMBER array[99999];  gives me more errors. One of them states: NUMBER isn't declared.

Comment: No. The only Expected warning/error should be: `[Warning] unused variable 'array' [-Wunused-variable]`. See the code here: http://ideone.com/JIjxy8

Comment: error: 'NUMBER' undeclared (first use in this function)
 error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
 error: for each function it appears in.)
error: expected ';' before 'array'

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using gcc to compile.

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
typedef  struct
    {       
        int   num ;
    } NUMBER ;
```

which is a shorthand for

```
struct anonymous_struct1
    {       
        int   num ;
    };
typedef struct anonymous_struct1 NUMBER ;
```

You have now two equivalent types:

```
struct anonymous_struct1
NUMBER
```

You can use them both, but `anonymous_struct1` is in the `struct` namespace and must always be preceded with `struct` in order to be used. (That is one major difference between C and C++.)

So either you just do

```
NUMBER array[99999];
```

or you define

```
typedef  struct number
    {       
        int   num ;
    } NUMBER ;
```

or simply

```
struct number
    {       
        int   num ;
    };
```

and then do

```
struct number array[99999];
```

Comment: struct number
    {       
        int   num ;
    };

Comment: I tried your last method, but it still says:  error: array type has incomplete element type

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. My struct contains a struct of itself. So I'm wondering if it's not defined yet?

Comment: It's because you can't define a sized array that includes a sized array of itself, and that makes sense obviously :P