# Array type has incomplete element type?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, ubuntu-14.04, system-calls

I am trying to write a program that passes information from the kernel space to the user space on ububtu 14.04. I declared a `struct` as the follows:

```
typedef struct
{
   long pid;
   char TTY[64];
   unsigned long long time; 
   char COMM[64]
  } myTasks;
```

In main, I then create an array of `myTasks` structs like:

```
struct myTasks taskInfo[2500]; 
//do stuff 
syscall(__NR_my_syscall2,numTasks,sizeof(taskInfo),taskInfo); // use it here
```

However, when I do that, I get a error on this line saying:

> struct myTasks taskInfo[2500] Error: array type has incomplete element

What am I doing wrong? I wanted to create an array of  `myTasks` structs that I could pass as a buffer to a syscall... but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to `C` so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about that syscall? Aren't you missing a closing parentheses somewhere?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks! However, thankfully its a mistake I only made typing it here :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C Compile Error: array type has incomplete element type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21080744/c-compile-error-array-type-has-incomplete-element-type)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You `typedef`ed the anonymous struct to `myTasks`. To declare your array, use `myTasks taskInfo[2500]`.

C thinks you are declaring a new *named* struct `struct myTasks`, and it's incomplete because you didn't define the struct. However, `myTasks` is an alias for the struct you already defined.

Comment: Oh.. so the it's a problem in my understanding of structs? So I should look into something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions)?

Comment: Yeah, that's a great resource! It looks like you just have some confusion on naming of the structs. In the code you provided, the struct you defined doesn't have a name; it's *anonymous*. You declared `myTasks` as an alias for that struct type. So it's like assigning a nickname to the struct. Later, you tried to declare an array containing `struct myTask`s, and `struct myTask` doesn't actually exist. C thought you were going to declare a new struct there, and since you didn't, it gave the error.

Comment: Thanks!! That makes a lot more sense, and I'll definitely read more into that link.

Answer (score 2):

`myTasks` is a *type-alias* and not a structure name. The correct use of it is e.g.

```
myTasks taskInfo[2500];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! :)